# react native compile error android - react-native-webview

Tags: android, react-native, compiler-errors

I was compiling with no errors and literally this showed up out of no where. has anyone else had this error?

Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: /user_data/projects/react-native/populi/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /user_data/projects/react-native/populi/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>   /user_data/projects/react-native/populi/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
>           Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>           is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Comment: I have the same problem. As far as I understand this is due to this google update : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases. The solution might be to migrate to androidx but it seems that react-native does not support androidx yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with one of your dependencies. In my case I started from a new react-native project and tried to add every dependency I have in my project and found that the problem was associated to `react-native-device-info` which was on version `0.13.0`.

After upgrading `react-native-device-info` to version `2.1.2` the problem is gone.

Comment: What the exact problem with the old version of this library?

Comment: answer: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503045776 The library used "services-gcm:+", and the new gcm version causes the problem.